# Razor syntax for DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

How can I write code below with a HTML helper?

```
<select name="CountryId">
    @foreach (var c in ViewBag.Counties) {
        <option value="@c.Id">@c.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

This code above will give the right html code in my browser. But if I use the HTML helper below the **value attribute** from the option tags are missing.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.CountryId, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Countries, "Name"), 
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }
)
```

What's wrong in this code if you know that `ViewBag.Counties` is an object from type `List<Country>` and has the properties `Name` (type of string) and `CounrtyId` (type of int).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.your selectlist item class should be created in the parent class that is model class you are binding in the view page.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId,new SelectList(ViewBag.Countries,"CountryID", "CountryName"),new {@class='form-control'})
```